# How to select text of an element by nightwatch.js using mouseButtonDown() function?

Tags: drag-and-drop, automated-tests, selection, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I am working automation testing using nightwatch.js, i am very new in this testing work, i want to perform text selection of an element, so i can make it highlight or note to selected text.

I am using mouseButtonDown(0) and mouseButtonUp(0) functions for selecting text but it is not selecting, my code is following.

```
'Make highlights by Dragging mouse' : function (client) {
  var bookView = client.page.book();
  bookView.loadBook();
  client.pause(3000);
  client.expect.element('.myDivClassId span:nth-child(1)').to.be.present;
  client.getLocation('.myDivClassId span:nth-child(1)', function(location) {
    client.moveToElement('.myDivClassId span:nth-child(1)', location.value.x, location.value.y);
    client.mouseButtonDown(0);
    console.log(location.value.x);
    console.log(location.value.y);
    var xValue = location.value.x;
    xValue = xValue + 200;
    console.log(xValue);
    client.moveToElement('.myDivClassId span:nth-child(1)', xValue, location.value.y);
    client.mouseButtonUp(0);
    client.pause(8000);
  });
  client.waitForElementVisible('.PopUp.Highlight', 5000);
  client.waitForElementVisible('.anchorLink a:nth-child(1)', 5000, function () {
    client.pause(1000);
    client.click('.anchorLink a:nth-child(1)');
    client.pause(10000);  
  });
}
```

i have tested mouseButtonDown() function using callback, it's working fine i am getting status 0, its mean mouseButtonDown() is working but text is not selecting . Is there any other way to test the mouseButtonDown() and mouseButtonUp function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, i use an example for making out things.

```
Example: <input id="gotopage" placeholder="4" data-page="4" data-totalpages="84" data-tabindex="12" tabindex="12">
```

Now get the value of input property placeholder using nightwatch function 'getAttribute' like below.

```
client.getAttribute('.page_of #gotopageform input#gotopage', 'placeholder', function(receivedValue) {
   this.assert.equal(receivedValue.value, 4);
});
```

now read question, using mouseButtonDown(0), so with mouseButtonDown() any selection is not possible, what you can do in this case, use moveToElement() function then use getAttribute() then use mouseButtonDown() function, so it will be way fetch the desired result for this question.

Done!!! :)